# Translate variables with POEdit/xgettext

Tags: php, variables, gettext, zend-translate, xgettext

I am using *PHP*, *Zend Framework* and Zend_Translate (gettext adapter). To edit translations I use *POEdit* which utilizes *xgettext* to fetch strings to be translated.

POEdit (xgettext) will search for keywords to find strings to translate. So, if searching for the keyword `translate`, POEdit will have no problem finding the `'Text to translate'` string when the text is passed to the translate function directly like:

```
echo translate('Text to translate');
```

But, in ofther cases strings will be passed to Zend functions that will do the translation for me, calling the translate function with a variable as a parameter:

```
function SomeZendFunction( $array ) {
    return translate( $array['string'] );
}

...

echo SomeZendFunction( array('string'=>'Another text to translate') );
// translate('Another text to translate');
```

This will cause POEdit (xgettext) to fail finding the string to translate. In the above example the string I wanted POEdit to find is `'Another text to translate'`, but since it is not passed directly to the `translate` function, it will not be found.

So, how to solve the problem?

My current solution is to create a dummy file containing a long list of all the strings that was not found by POEdit:

```
<?php // Dummy file, only accessed by POEdit when scanning for strings to translate
translate('Text to translate');
translate('Another text to translate');
translate('A third text to translate');
....
```

But the downside of this solution is that when updating a string, I both need to change the dummy file and find the original string. This will make it more hard to maintain.

Another solution I thought of was adding the translation string to a comment after calling `SomeZendFunction` (See the above example), but I fail to make xgettext accept it as it ignores comments.

So, anyone knows how to make xgettext to accept strings within comments? Or anyone has any other solution that might be better?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:**

I don't know for what reason I was down voted. But I've tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it! By creating a dummy function

```
function t($string) {
    return $string;
}

echo SomeZendFunction( t('Another text to translate') );
```

I can add this `t` function to the translate keywords in POEdit. Then I can embed all strings that will later on be translated by Zend into this Dummy function.

This way Zend will be allowed to translate it, and POEdit will recognize it as a string to translate.

If anyone has a better solution, please post it.

Comment: I used PHP function _ for that

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use a dummy function and pass strings to it, why no refactor the someZendFunction to accept a string parameter and then add that function name "someZendFunction" to the list in the poedit keywords? That eliminates the extra function calls and makes the code a bit cleaner.
Or you could wrap that "someZendFunction"  into the t(9 function so that it does the dirty work for you! that will also save you from extra typing!

Example:

```
function t($str){
    echo someZendFunction($str);
}
```

and then somewhere in  your code:

```
t('Translate this string please!');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand your answer. Embedding would work if you have a more limited set of functions. Adding other functions to PoEdit works if the text is only declare in connection with function calls. But sometimes it is declare prehand: `$array = array('add'=>t('Add'), 'del'=>t('Delete')); someZendFunction($array);` . But thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

As the word say, "Variable" means that the value varies from time to time, so there is no possibility to know in advance what will be the value. The way you are looking to translate is incorrect.

Comment: I _do_ know what string to translate, but since the translation is done within Zend_Framework, I can't do it the direct way. So yes, for the translate function, it is a variable. But I still know all the static strings. I just need a way to tell POEdit that this string will be translated..

Comment: Ok. What kind of variables do you like to translate ? Can you show us some variables ?

Comment: Well, the `$array` is a variable

Comment: You are not help me ! :) xaxa

In any case.

I will try to guess what you need.

One option is to use (s)printf to format the variables into another string

Another option is to use I18n properly in order to have all your data in any language you need.

Comment: Oh, I think you've misunderstood the question. Yes, I know how to use (s)printf, but my problem is how to make POEdit detect the string, if the static string is first stored in a variable before being passed to the translate function which xgettext is actually looking for.

Comment: I try to give you my best result :). In anyway. If the ammount of your variables that need translation are not too much you can pass that records in *.po file manualy. Have you try it ? Is too easy. especialy if these strings are in singular. The only thing you have to do is to add a line with msgid "here is your original text" and another line with msgstr "This is my translated text". I hope that helps

Comment: It is not the solution to my problem, but it sure is a good idea (so, I'll up it!). The project is unfortunately too big to manage in that manner. Thanks for the help :)