# Poedit - Update from source - Not working with constant

Tags: php, symfony, po, poedit

**Context :**
I currently have an hybrid application.
I've been using poedit as a tool to generate keys within my .po files and thus far, everything works fine.

Altough I've encountered a weird situation and i can't find anything relevant on the web. You are my best hope stackoverflow-kenobi.

**Explanation :**
I'm currently refactoring some code, and assessed that we have many error message that have been duplicated throughout the application.

I've created some constants to be used like that

```
public const ERROR_UNKNOWN = 'An stupid error happenned, but we don't know why';
```

I've then worked in my controller to display the correct error message.

```
//some code
$this->translator->translate(self::ERROR_UNKNOWN);
//more code
```

**Problem :** When doing this, the keys are not in the .po files anymore.

Has anyone encountered this situation ? Have you find any solution to make things work ?
I haven't seen anyone talking about this on the web. Hope someone here found something.

Have a nice day, and thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you want is `xgettext` to parse variables?

**Spoiler**: not that easy (afaik)

The best I can think of is to trick it into parsing your keys, in this fashion: [Translate variables with POEdit/xgettext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644302/translate-variables-with-poedit-xgettext)

You could list all possible errors in a dedicated dictionary (which would be `xgettext` "parsable") and only store the keys in constants

Comment: But you're not passing the string as an argument, are you?

Comment: No since the point of having a constant is not to duplicate said string. If I have to wrote it twice the whole refacto has no sense.

Comment: I see, but then you can't use constants or you would have to change your tooling.